# How to find video in Firefox cache?

Tags: firefox, browser-cache

I'm trying to find youtube video (just watched) in Firefox cache folder, but I cant find the folder.
win xp sp3
Firefox 16.1
I tried

```
C:\Documents and Settings\eDIN\Local Settings\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xp44aixq.default\Cache
```

Also

```
C:\Documents and Settings\eDIN\Local Settings\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\49mvq84u.default\Cache
```

In this folder I found the png thumbnail of visited youtube page

```
C:\Documents and Settings\eDIN\Local Settings\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\49mvq84u.default\thumbnails
```

But, there is no video file.
I also searched all files and folders arround (Default user, All users...etc).
There is only one win user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video will be there in the cache only as long as you are seeing it in the browser, after which it is deleted automatically.
I would recommend using plugins provided by modern browsers if you want to download the video.

Comment: Mayank, are you sure. I found so many sites where is explained that the video should exist in cache till browser is closed?

Comment: Now, I searched the folders DURING the video watching. No result.

Comment: Did you check about:cache ?

Comment: Yes, I did. `file on disk: C:\Documents and Settings\eDIN\Local Settings\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\49mvq84u.default\Cache\4\3A\65440d01` but there is no such a file on the disk

Comment: i checked it on Windows 7.
The file exists but not as a regular video file.
i think that it would also depend on how much space you have left in the cache.
win 7 has around 300 Mb of cache

Comment: The cache should exist there, because otherwise the main objective of caching would become invalid

Answer (score 9):

You can check the cache file easily by going to the following:

> about:cache

Enter the above into your URL or location bar.

Comment: about:cache is slow. It doesn't sort. It doesn't filter. Search works (^F), but you don't know the name.

Answer (score 4):

> **THIS ANSWER IS ONLY FOR FINDING FLASH VIDEOS.**

Tested version

**Firefox 38.0.5**

**Shockwave Flash 17.0 r0**

Latest Firefox with latest Flash player on Windows will save the Flash videos in

```
C:\Users\<your user account>\AppData\Local\Temp\acro_rd_dir\
```

The file will be something like `fla****.tmp`. You have to change the `.tmp` extension to `.flv` extension to make it playable (Most modern players will accept a drag and drop of the file even without changing its extension).

**** If you have trouble in finding the folder 
Hit **<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>** and in the popup **Run Dialog** copy and paste this

```
%appdata%\..\Local\Temp\acro_rd_dir\
```

and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding viewing the cache contents, there's a nice Firefox extension named [CacheViewer Continued](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/cacheviewer-continued/?src=search) - like the name suggests, it's a fork of the CacheViewer.

Regarding the question about YouTube video being in cache, I've answered a [related question](https://superuser.com/questions/484295/caching-youtube-videos-across-loads/497698) yesterday. Basically, most of the videos you watch on YouTube won't be cached -- if they exceed certain size (you don't want to purge your whole cache after watching several videos).

If you want to download videos, you can use [one of the addons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=youtube+) from addons.mozilla.org or [userscripts](http://userscripts.org/tags/youtube). By the way, you can also view URLs of all the resources loaded on the page (including audio and video files) by opening AdBlock Plus' "Open blockable items" menu.

Answer (score 1):

**Use Firebug!**

The OP has already said he's using Firefox, so he might as well take advantage of that fact.

Install the "Firebug" add-on, then follow these fantastic instructions:

https://web.archive.org/web/20180226215253/http://bengreen.eu/fancyhtml/techiestuff/youtubedownloadwithfirebug.html

It gives "videos from Youtube" as an example, but the same applies to any other content you might find in a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem as the OP for a long time. At least since 2011 youtube changed the way its videos are cached and since then its hard to find them.
The old way it used to be stored on the regular Windows Temp folder on the Windows use folder. Sometimes, I don't know when, you can indeed find it there, for that I usually use this really lightweight freeware called VideoCacheView because it searches all IE and windows related folders really quick and can copy those nasty 'locked', in use files with just a right click instead of me having to use the command line with hobocopy tool.
I tried to search the Firefox cache and it was no good.
My guess is youtube is using some nonstandard Flash cache method, probably on the Flash cache folder itself but I only found that folder once or twice, shouldnt be hard though.

Comment: Can you link to source for this information or better yet to definitive answer?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using win XP I think it should be found in the temp folder,
just write %temp% in the address bar then there should be a file which its name contains "fla" and had a reasonable size (depends on the opened video).
the problem is that you can not copy the file because you will get an error stats the file is being used... and soon after you close Firefox the file will be disappeared. So what to do?
to solve this problem you should switch your user and log off the user from another user using task manger. then com back and copy the file and change the extension from .tmp to .flv then open the file. I know that km player can read the file.

Answer (score -1):

One of the easiest ways to download streaming videos from any site containing it, is passing the url to jdownloader. There are some addons like Flash Video Downloader too.
I've maid a simple script (I'm a learner) for linux to cache pictures and videos (but doesn't work with firefox unless I start a download with Flash Video Downloader first):

http://lapaginadefran.webs.com/apps/blog/show/25169891-firefox-cache-recover

Answer (score -1):

It copies the file despite the process being in use:

http://www.nirsoft.net/articles/copy_flash_flv_temp_file.html

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.